# What type of display is this?

Tags: lcd, display

I found this display in this cheap chinese handheld tetris. It doesn't have any connectors on itself and is just sitting on small PCB with some kind of gum between them. What kind of display is it and how can I power it with eg. arduino?

[image: display]
[image: display]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a simple custom LCD. The "gum" you are talking about is called a Zebra Strip and it transfers the signals from the PCB to the display. Some pressure is required for a good connection, so some sort of bracket is normally used to hold the LCD in place.

[image]

The LCD does not have an integrated display driver, it will be located on the PCB. If you really wanted to make use of this LCD, your best bet would be to hack the game itself and somehow tap into the LCD driver. To be honest, it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Yes pressure is indeed needed for it to work. Thanks for fast answer.

Comment: I forgot to ask is there a way i can avoid using rubber strips and solder directly or somehow connect it to wires?

Comment: @AleXstX Not really. Soldering is out of question. Pressing wires to the LCD could work electrically, but hacking the PCB would be much easier than making a bracket to hold the wires...

Comment: It's a raw LCD, therefore the driving signals are moderately complex (AC at a couple hundred Hz, etc).  I agree that it is more trouble than it's worth unless you specifically wanted to learn how to make an LCD driver.